drop down menu items not being selectable in web page using data list and java
I'm writing a code with html for a login page in order to get wifi ssid and password from user and connect esp32 to a local modem using a mobile phone as a medium. when i click on the ssid section the drop down menu is populated correctly by the server side and is shown. the problem is that these ssids are not selectable and when i click on them nothing happens. i tried googling and asking AI for help but it didnt work.
here is my html code
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Wi-Fi Selection</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./normalize.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
</head>
<body>
<form action="/get" name="Divertpage" class="form-horizontal login-form">
  <div class="form-group relative">
    <div class="form" id="form">
      <div class="field email">
        <div class="icon"></div>
        <fieldset>
          <label>انتخاب شبکه مورد نظر</label>
          <input autocomplete="off" role="combobox" list="ssidList" id="input" name="ssid" placeholder="شبکه مورد نظر را انتخاب کنید">
          <!-- The list attribute should match the id of the datalist -->
          <datalist id="ssidList" role="listbox">
          </datalist>
        </fieldset>

        <div class="field password">
          <div class="icon"></div>
          <input class="input" id="password" type="password" placeholder="رمز عبور"/>
        </div>
        <button class="button" type="submit" onclick="WaitPls()">ذخیره
          <div class="side-top-bottom"></div>
          <div class="side-right-left"></div>
        </button>
        <small>فرم را پر کنید</small>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>

<script src='./jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src="./script.js"></script>
<script>
  // Fetch scanned Wi-Fi networks and populate the dropdown
  function fetchWifiNetworks() {
    fetch('/wifi_scan')
      .then(response => response.text())
      .then(data => {
        document.getElementById('ssidList').innerHTML = data;
      });
  }

  // Call fetchWifiNetworks on page load
  window.onload = fetchWifiNetworks;

  function WaitPls() {
    var ssid = document.forms["Divertpage"]["ssid"].value;
    var password = document.forms["Divertpage"]["password"].value;

    if (ssid == "") {
      // alert("نام کاربری را وارد نمایید.");
      return false;
    } else if (password == "") {
      // alert("رمز عبور را وارد نمایید.");
      return false;
    } else {
      // Redirect to waiting page after form submission
      window.location.href = "/Wait";
    }
  }
</script>

<script>
  var input = document.getElementById('input');
  var ssid = document.getElementById('ssidList');

  input.onfocus = function () {
    ssid.style.display = 'block';
    input.style.borderRadius = "5px 5px 0 0";  
  };
  
  input.oninput = function() {
    var text = input.value.toUpperCase();
    for (let option of ssid.options) {
      if(option.value.toUpperCase().indexOf(text) > -1){
        option.style.display = "block";
      } else {
        option.style.display = "none";
      }
    };
  };

  for (let option of ssid.options) {
    option.onclick = function () {
      input.value = option.value;
      ssid.style.display = 'none';
      input.style.borderRadius = "5px";
    }
  };
  
  var currentFocus = -1;

  function addActive(x) {
    if (!x) return false;
    removeActive(x);
    if (currentFocus >= x.length) currentFocus = 0;
    if (currentFocus < 0) currentFocus = (x.length - 1);
    x[currentFocus].classList.add("active");
  }
  
  function removeActive(x) {
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      x[i].classList.remove("active");
    }
  }
</script>

</body>
</html>

and here is the task I use to populate SSIDs in server CPP code:
void wifiScanTask(void *parameter)
{
  while (true)
  {
      Serial.println("scanning networks");
      int n = WiFi.scanNetworks();
      if (n > 0)
      {
        scannedNetworks = "<option value=\"\">انتخاب شبکه مورد نظر</option>";
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        {
          scannedNetworks += "<option value=\"" + WiFi.SSID(i) + "\">" + WiFi.SSID(i) + "</option>";
          if (i == (n - 1))
          {
            Serial.println("i is n-1");
            wifi_scan_resume_flag=1;
            first_time_scan=0;
            vTaskSuspend(NULL);
            
         
          }
        }
      }
      else
      {
        scannedNetworks = "<option value=\"\">شبکه ای یافت نشد</option>";
      }
    // Wait for 10 seconds before scanning again
    vTaskDelay(20000 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
  }
}


what might be the problem here?
thanks in advance.
i tried disabling the other java scripts that are not related to drop down menu but it did not work.

@hcheung thanks for your response but i didnt write the tag you said i used datalist tag which is a valid tag and is used frequently. another thing which is noteworthy to mention is that i used select at first but i need to be able to type the ssid at the same time in the same place where i can choose one of multiple ssids
